# vuex state mutations blocks UI

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am loading a csv file in a webworker and then push chunks of around 600 elements to the state in a loop:

```
mutations: {
 LOAD_ITEMS: (state, { items }) => {
  items.forEach(item => {
    Vue.set(state.items, item.id, item)
    state.lists.all.push(item.id)
    state.lists.active.push(item.id)
  })
 }
}
```

The timeline shows, that adding stuff to the state is blocking the UI. So do I have to manage the state mutations in terms of performance also on my own ?

Or is the vuex / vue state not meant for datasets of around 1000-7000 objects ?

[image: profile]

Comment: Your async fetching is done in action, not mutation itself, right?

Comment: yes, the fetching is done in an action called FETCH_ITEMS

Comment: Seems to me, the creation of all those observers is blocking. I would be happy to know, how to handle large datasets for e.g. data visualization with an observer based state like the vuex store.